# The usage of comma in CSS declarations

Tags: css

What is the logic behind the usage of the comma in CSS declarations?

Sometimes it is required, sometimes it is optional, and sometimes it generates an error.

```
<div>test</div>

<style>
div {
    height: 200px;

    background:
        /* Comma between colors is required. */
        linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)),
        /* Comma between 1st and 2nd line is optional. */
        rgb(255, 0, 0);

    /* There must not be a comma. */
    filter: brightness(90%) contrast(90%);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For background we need comma because it's multiple background layer. So, each time we add a new background layer, we need a comma. Technically, they are **independent** layers. We can omit the comma before the final layer if it's defined as a color.

For the filter, we are applying **one** filter which is the combination of multiple filter functions. The same as with transform property. Technically they aren't independant values.

---

In all the cases you should refer to the specification to get the syntax of each property as there is no *magic* rule behind the use of comma, space, or any other character. The main purpose is to have a clear and non-ambiguous syntax.

[For background](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background)

> Value: `<bg-layer>`# , `<final-bg-layer>`

```
 <bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box>

 <final-bg-layer> =  <\'background-color'> || <bg-image> || <bg-position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box>
```

> A hash mark (`#`) indicates that the preceding type, word, or group occurs one or more times, **separated by comma tokens** (which may optionally be surrounded by white space and/or comments). It may optionally be followed by the curly brace forms, above, to indicate precisely how many times the repetition occurs, like #{1,4}. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#component-multipliers)</sup>

[For colors](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#colorunits):

> The format of an RGB value in the functional notation is `rgb(` followed by a **comma-separated list of three numerical values** (either three integer values or three percentage values) followed by `)`. The integer value 255 corresponds to 100%, and to F or FF in the hexadecimal notation: r`gb(255,255,255) = rgb(100%,100%,100%) = #FFF`. White space characters are allowed around the numerical values.

[For filter](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#FilterProperty)

> Value: `none` | `<filter-value-list>`

```
 <filter-value-list> = [ <filter-function> | <url> ]+
```

> A plus (`+`) indicates that the preceding type, word, or group occurs one or more times.

---

Worth to note that in background you can have comma, space and also `/` to separate different values like described in the above syntax.

```
 background:linear-gradient(red,red) left/100% 50px,
            linear-gradient(blue,blue) top/50px 20px yellow;
```

Comma is the separation between layers and space is the separation between different properties. We can write it differently like below:

```
 backgrund-image:linear-gradient(red,red),linear-gradient(blue,blue);
 background-position:left,top;
 background-size:100% 50px,50px 20px;
 background-color:yellow;
```

Answer (score 3):

`brightness` and `contrast` are two separate values of the filter property.

`rgba` and individual rgb values are parameters of the `rgba` and `linear-gradient` functions, in this case `linear-gradient` is the value of the `background` property.

Edit: also worth noting there is a major exception to this rule: `font-family` takes several values separated by commas... So no this isn't entirely consistent.

Comment: It still inconsistent, isn't it? The comma between `filter` values is wrong, whereas the comma between `background` values is optional.

Comment: Both answers are great. For the sake of justice, I accepted the answer of Temani Afif (without upvoting) and upvoted yours :-)

Comment: Temani's answer is much more complete, you've made the good decision.